# Combinations without repetition of two variables that can change in number

Tags: combinatorics

I have two engine types, lets call them small and large. I want to find the formula for the varying combinations of using them without repetition.

Suppose the number of engines are n_small = 2, n_large = 2.

When I count the combinations myself I get:

```
No engines used   : 1 (Since no engine is used)
1 engine  used    : 2 (We can have one small or one large running)
2 engines used    : 3 (two small, two large or one small and one large)
3 engines used    : 2 (two small one large, or two large one small)
4 engines used    : 1 (two small, two large)
```

Which equals 9 combinations. How can I make a formula for this, so that I know the number of combinations if n_small and n_large vary? My goal is to make a list of all combinations when n_small and n_large varies.

Answer (score 0):

A subset is completely determined by how many large and small engines are used.  If there are $l$ large engines and $s$ small engines available, we have $l + 1$ choices for the number of large engines that are used ($0, 1, 2, \ldots, l$) and $s + 1$ choices for the number of small engines that are used ($0, 1, 2, \ldots, s + 1$).  Hence, there are $(l + 1)(s + 1)$ to form a subset of the $l + s$ engines.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $(n+1)^2$. Look at the table:
[image]

Along the row and column are given the numbers of small and large engines and in cells the number of engines working. For $3\times3$, the grid has $4\times 4$ cells totaling $16$.